# Manage Metadata service extension to a different farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, managed-metadata

How to extend Manage Metadata service to a different farm? what are the correct steps involved?

Answer (score 0):

This [Technet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621100.aspx) explains in detail what is need. In short these are the required steps:

1. Exchange trust certificates between the farms
2. On the publishing farm, publish the service application
3. On the consuming farm, set the permission to the appropriate service applications
4. On the consuming farm, connect to the remote service application
5. Add the shared service application to a Web application proxy group on the consuming farm
6. Configure server-to-server authentication between the publishing and consuming farms